# How to make different button for null and not null?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like to do different button when there is null(no image) in the database. But, it shows two buttons instead of one button only. Can you guys help me? I tried at the frontend only. If there are solutions to do at the backend, please share some codes.

This is the codes that I've tried at the frontend.

```
<a href="#" id="ImageButton2" class="btn btn-success" visible='<%# If(IsDBNull(Eval("ImagePic")), True, False)%>'>No Image</a>
<a href="#" id="ImageButton" class="btn btn-success" visible='<%# If(IsDBNull(Eval("ImagePic")), False, True)%>' onclick="popitup('Fetch_Image.aspx?id=' + <%# Eval("id")%>); return false;">Actual Image</a> </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html anchor tag doesn't have an attribute `visible`. You either meant to use a server side control like asp:HyperLink which does have a Visible property an will render the appropriate html, or you need to set the visibility by CSS style on your client side html, for example by controlling the `display` property:

```
<a ... style='display: <%# If(IsDBNull(Eval("ImagePic")), "inline", "none")%>'>No Image</a>
```

Comment: You need to to swap the "inline" and "none" over to invert the display logic for the other button

Comment: swap like this?
                                                 <a href="#" id="ImageButton2" class="btn btn-success" style='display: <%# If(IsDBNull(Eval("ImagePic")), "none", "inline")%>'>No Image</a>
                                                   <a href="#" id="ImageButton" class="btn btn-success" style='display: <%# If(IsDBNull(Eval("ImagePic")), "inline", "NOT NULL")%>' onclick="popitup('Fetch_Image.aspx?id=' + <%# Eval("id")%>); return false;">Actual Image</a> </td>                          its working too but this time it shows one button for NOT NULL and two buttons for NULL.

Comment: No, swap like `"inline", "none"` -> `"none", "inline"`. Before you had `True,False`, and `False,True`. Same idea